# Laravel 5.7 Handle email verification errors from API

Tags: api, email, error-handling, laravel-5.7

I'm using laravel 5.7 to build an API REST.

When I add the `verified` middleware to my route group and I try to login with an unverified user by my client api, I get the error `400` `Bad request`. This error is too generic and don't show the problem clearly for my customer (it's happens in a login form).

[image]

If I to edit the `render()` method in `Handler.php` to ignore the `isApiCall()` and return `parent::render($request, $e);`, so I get the full error (`Your email address is not verified`, status `403`), but when I try to return this in a json object with `response()->json([$e])`, the response is always empty.

[image]
[image]

So how to handle properly the api errors to be return the full message from exception, in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have already solved this problem, but this solution might help someone else:

The reason why your response was returning an empty array is because you were passing an Exception type object into the json function that is expecting an array. The response should look like this:

```
return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
```

This will return a json response like:

```
{
"message": "Your email address is not verified"
}
```